# Pressing ALT+ARROW_KEYS in Visual Studio editor writes single ASCII character

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, visual-studio-2013, ascii

I am using VS2013 as my IDE and ever since the installation it acts very oddly when pressing ALT and any of the ARROW keys. I use ALT+LEFT and ALT+RIGHT to navigate backward/forward which works in principal but once VS completes the jump it writes out a single character.

This is after the jump/after pressing ALT+LEFT:

[image: This is after the jump/after pressing ALT+LEFT]

Those are the characters that are being written:

- ALT+UP: ◘
- ALT+RIGHT: ♠
- ALT+DOWN: ☻
- ALT+LEFT: ♦

I am using VS2013 at work as well all the time and I have never seen this before. I know that pressing ALT+NUMPAD_KEYS produces [ASCII characters](http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html) but why is that happening for my arrow keys and only in VS? Apparently ALT+RIGHT for me is the same as pressing ALT+6. In fact pressing ALT+6 and ALT+RIGHT in VS yields the same character '♠'. I have not been able to reproduce this behavior in any other application thus far. I actually swapped out my keyboard to see if its got anything to do with that. No joy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Okay I have found the cause thanks to Hans Passant on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581002/1352384

I did a diagnostic boot and discovered the issue even then still persisted. I then went on to kill all remaining processes until I struck gold:

[image: the bad guy]

With this process gone ALT+ARROW_KEYS dont trigger ASCII symbol insertion anymore. Now I am looking into what this process actually does, if its malicious and how best to remove it from startup. I'll keep you posted.

#### Update:

I ended up doing two things in total to get rid of this process.

1. Reinstalled .NET Framework 4.5.1
2. Renamed/Removed this file: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegSvcs.exe`

On booting into Windows there are no errors pertaining to that particular executable nor have I noticed any other malfunctions. Just to be sure I ran a couple of virus/malware removal tools. They all came up with no threats.